# How to get date in the following format on linux terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

If I type "date" on the Linux terminal, it shows Thu Apr 29 12:44:24 EDT 2021.

Is there a way to show it in the following format using a command on the Linux terminal or shell script?

2021-04-29T12:44:24.634938+00:00

Indicated Precision: Microseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see `man date` or https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html

```
date -Ins
```

or

```
date --iso-8601=ns
```

prints e.g.

```
2021-04-29T19:07:36.759087300+02:00
```

I didn't find an option to print microseconds instead of nanoseconds. If necessary you might have to post-process the output to chop off the last 3 digits of the nanoseconds value.

Example:

```
date -Ins|sed 's/\([.][[:digit:]]\{6\}\)[[:digit:]]\{0,3\}/\1/'
```

If the decimal point is always followed by exactly 9 digits you can use

```
date -Ins|sed 's/\(\.......\).../\1/'
```

ISO 8601 doesn't specify the precision of the fractions of a second, so the number of digits after the decimal point is not necessarily fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. As suggested in the documentation, in --iso-8601[=FMT], FMT='date' for date only (the default), 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds', or 'ns' for date and time to the indicated precision. Is there a way to bring the precision to microseconds instead of nanoseconds?

Answer (score 0):

See `man date` if `date` command installed on your host supports `--iso-8601[` command line option.
You can use sed or perl to convert nano-seconds to micro-seconds:

```
date -Ins | perl -pe 's/(\d{6})\d{3}([-+])/$1$2/'
```

`man date`

> **-I[FMT], --iso-8601[=FMT]**
> output  date/time  in  ISO 8601 format.  FMT='date' for date only (the default), 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds', or 'ns' for date and time to the indicated precision.
> Example: 2006-08-14T02:34:56-06:00

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. As suggested in the documentation, in --iso-8601[=FMT], FMT='date' for date only (the default), 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds', or 'ns' for date and time to the indicated precision. Is there a way to bring the precision to microseconds instead of nanoseconds?

Comment: In the worst case you can use sed or perl : `date -Ins | perl -pe 'print ; s/(\d{6})\d{3}([-+])/$1$2/'`